# Map a value to an other in SQL

Tags: sql

I have following SQL and corresponding result. What I have to do to get the following expected result. I mean I wantı map numeric value to varchar value decription.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
  STATUS
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY STATUS;
```

---

```
 COUNT(*) STATUS
---------- ----------
         4          8 
        47          1 
       100         11
```

**Expected result**

```
 COUNT(*) STATUS
---------- ----------
         4          INVALID
        47          FAIL
       100         SUCCESS
```

Comment: Do you have a table that contains the mappings? If so, just join with it. If not, use `CASE`.

Comment: some sample data would help!

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114 No it wouldn't. The answer is obvious without it.

Comment: If you are doing the mapping using something like CASE or DECODE then the syntax depends on the version of SQL.  If that is the case, please tag this question MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / PostgreSQL / etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
        CASE STATUS
            WHEN 8 THEN 'INVALID'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'FAIL'
            WHEN 11 THEN 'SUCCESS'
            ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
        END AS STATUS
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY STATUS
```

If you have a table that maps status codes to names, it would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), b.NAME
FROM TABLEA AS a
JOIN TABLEB AS b ON a.STATUS = b.STATUS
GROUP BY b.NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

For the question given below, using `DECODE` as below would solve the purpose:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
DECODE(STATUS, '1'  , 'FAIL',
               '8'  , 'INVALID, 
               '11' , 'SUCCESS'  
                    , 'INVALID_STATUS') STATUS
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY STATUS;
```

I have assumed that you would map as follows:

```
STATUS   |  STATUSTEXT
1        |  FAIL
8        |  INVALID
11       |  SUCCESS
ANYOTHER |  INVALID_STATUS
```

If you have a separate status master table, then you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) RECORD_COUNT, b.STATUS_NAME  STATUS_TEXT
FROM TABLEA A,TABLEB AS b 
WHERE
B.STATUS = A.STATUS (+)
GROUP BY b.STATUS_NAME
```

TABLEB would have columns and values as

```
STATUS   |  STATUS_NAME
---------+---------------
1        |  FAIL
8        |  INVALID
11       |  SUCCESS
15       |  IGNORE
```

Using `(+)` would give you the count against all statuses. If there is no record with a particular status say D, then D will also be displayed in your output with corresponding value as 0